# Echart graph does not change color

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, echarts

I'm trying to change the color of my eCharts graph but the change doesn't apply.

Here is my code :

```
this.option.series.push({
  name: 'Real',
  type: 'line',
  symbol: 'triangle',
    symbolSize: 10,
    label: {
            normal: {
                show: true,
                position: 'left'
            }
        },
    lineStyle: {
        color: 'transparent',
        width: 2,
        type: 'line'
    },
    itemStyle: {
        color: 'green'
    },
  markLine: {
    data: [
      {
        name: 'Limite',
        yAxis: 500,
        lineStyle:
        {
          color: 'red'
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  data: realData
});
```

When I try this code to the eCharts snippet(on the official documentation [here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-style)) it work but not in my works.

I'm using Angular v8 and echarts 3.8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want change line's color or item's color?

You can check this example https://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=xXbP45bsC

and here a serie's configuration

```
    {
        name: '注册总量',
        type: 'line',
        // smooth: true, //是否平滑
        showAllSymbol: true,
        // symbol: 'image://./static/images/guang-circle.png',
        symbol: 'circle',
        symbolSize: 25,
        lineStyle: {
            normal: {
                color: "#00ca95",
                shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)',
                shadowBlur: 0,
                shadowOffsetY: 5,
                shadowOffsetX: 5,
            },
        },
        label: {
            show: true,
            position: 'top',
            textStyle: {
                color: '#00ca95',
            }
        },

        itemStyle: {
            color: "#00ca95",
            borderColor: "#fff",
            borderWidth: 3,
            shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)',
            shadowBlur: 0,
            shadowOffsetY: 2,
            shadowOffsetX: 2,
        },
        tooltip: {
            show: false
        },
        areaStyle: {
            normal: {
                color: new echarts.graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [{
                        offset: 0,
                        color: 'rgba(0,202,149,0.3)'
                    },
                    {
                        offset: 1,
                        color: 'rgba(0,202,149,0)'
                    }
                ], false),
                shadowColor: 'rgba(0,202,149, 0.9)',
                shadowBlur: 20
            }
        },
        data: [281.55, 398.35, 214.02, 179.55, 289.57, 356.14, ],
    }
```

Regards

Comment: Hello Charly, 
Thank you for your answer.

I want to change the line's color,  I don't why, what I did didn't work but your serie's configuration work I'll adapt the color for which I want thank's a lot

Comment: You are welcome, in this link https://gallery.echartsjs.com/explore.html#sort=rank~timeframe=all~author=all there are a lot of examples, included a tetris game he he